# Is asp.net MultiView support in IE 8?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

In my page I am using MultiView for hiding grid-view and switch it when it's needed. It's totally cool in chrome and Firefox. But in IE8 it is showing as a new Pop-Up window(The whole page is displaying inside window.showModalDialog so an another popup really not good). Is any one face similar problem or can you please give me an advise.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes i m using. Could u show your code

Comment: I can't see any problem using it. Maybe you could post your code?

Comment: What is your code for hiding and showing?

Comment: @Alexander MultiViewLists.ActiveViewIndex = 1; in buttonclick event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use  window.open instead window.showModalDialog, this will help

Comment: post this as a comment or else elaborate